# how to fix facebook like button in genymoution

Tags: android, facebook, android-emulator, facebook-like, genymotion

I write application for android with use this code

Java code:

```
LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.likeView);
likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);

likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
        "https://www.facebook.com/coca-cola",
        LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH);
```

layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="example.tmp.ShareActivity">

    <com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
        android:id="@+id/likeView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but when I click to LIKE button fast open and close facebook UI and get this error

```
09-24 15:34:37.191 3865-3865/example.tmp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught Error: Module CircularBuffer has not been defined", source: https://m.facebook.com/connect/dialog/MPlatformLikeJSDialog?app_id=740226516083368&method_args=%7B%22object_id%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.facebook.com%5C%2Fcoca-cola%22%2C%22object_type%22%3A%22open_graph%22%7D&bridge_args=%7B%22action_id%22%3A%2273277a64-873b-4d31-8c14-0d9d064b4271%22%7D&display=touch&android_key_hash=tt4i17WFZzKyTAyD2L8taqrThUk%0A (1)
09-24 15:34:37.892 3865-3936/example.tmp E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000f (glSizeof,80)
09-24 15:34:38.084 3865-3936/example.tmp E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000f (glSizeof,80)
09-24 15:34:38.441 3865-3936/example.tmp E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000f (glSizeof,80)
09-24 15:34:38.789 3865-3936/example.tmp E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000f (glSizeof,80)
09-24 15:34:38.982 3865-3936/example.tmp E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000f (glSizeof,80)
09-24 15:34:39.304 3865-3936/example.tmp E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000f (glSizeof,80)
09-24 15:34:39.505 3865-3936/example.tmp E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000f (glSizeof,80)
09-24 15:34:39.732 3865-3936/example.tmp E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000f (glSizeof,80)
09-24 15:34:39.892 3865-3936/example.tmp E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000f (glSizeof,80)
09-24 15:34:40.061 3865-3936/example.tmp E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000f (glSizeof,80)
09-24 15:34:40.252 3865-3936/example.tmp E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000f (glSizeof,80)
09-24 15:34:40.473 3865-3936/example.tmp E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000f (glSizeof,80)
09-24 15:34:40.755 3865-3936/example.tmp E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x73000f (glSizeof,80)
09-24 15:34:40.777 3865-3865/example.tmp I/Choreographer: Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

maybe anybody know - how I can fix this bug in genymoution emulator?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have followed the [instructions in the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button)? Specifically, did you properly implement your `Activity`'s `onActivityResult()`, and did you modify your `AndroidManifest.xml` like the [Getting Started docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) explain?

Comment: Where is that LikeView code implemented in your Android `Activity`?

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same issue. Problem was in wrong user. I tried to test LikeView with user which doesn't have permission for this app. When I tested with another user everything works like a charm. So try to add role permission for this user or test on another account